# Printing image on transparency without scrunching it

Tags: printing, printer, image-processing, transparency, toner

I have some transparencies which I bought from staples office store. They are meant for all different kinds of printers (they have a coating on one side).

When I tried printing on them, I noticed that I have to load a full sheet into the main paper tray of my brother HL-L2320D USB printer just to get it to print correctly.

If I load it in the front paper feeder, then 99% of the time, the paper scrunches up.

The reason I'm using transparencies is because I make my own circuit boards through the photo-graphic method (think old-fashioned photography).  Sometimes my circuit board artwork is way too small to fit a whole sheet so I tend to put a bunch of circuits together on one page which is also tedious thanks to the software not helping.

When I had my previous printer (brother HL-2040), I was able to print on transparencies without them scrunching up. Now I think technology is getting worse when it comes to printing transparencies since I was one of the 5% that still use transparencies.

So rather than me trying to put a bunch of circuits together and/or blowing money on full sheets of transparencies just to use 1/8th of the sheet, are there any special tricks or methods I should follow when loading small sheets of transparencies into a lazer printer without them crunching up?

I always print them so the toner goes on the side opposite of the coating.

Answer (score 0):

The substrate is probably slipping. Check your manual, but there appears to be a "straight feed path" option for your printer: there is a flip-down section on the back of the printer so the paper can be ejected out the back. It may require using manual feed. Sometimes this helps.

Comment: I use linux and there is an option for "InputSlot" which gives me choices "Tray1" and "Manual Feed". but I don't see "straight feed path".

Comment: @mike: theck your manual. It will be an actual door or flap on the back of the printer, not a setting to select.

Comment: I actually did get away with printing a half-sheet by adjusting the plastic paper tab in the paper tray compartment. I think I'll settle for that.